# Blazor is showing a validation message without a validation attribute

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, blazor

I took over support for a Blazor application using .NET Core 3.1 and I have added code for validation but I have validation messages showing for some controls that have no validation attributes or ValidationMessage tags, and validation messages show where I do have the attributes and validation message tags as expected. I have no idea why messages are showing were there isn't an attribute or validation message tag. The message is displayed for the **GasComps[0].Quantity** shown below. The message is stating that the numbers need to be whole numbers, because if I change the value to 1.5 the message states the nearest valid values are 0 and 1. I cannot find any place in the code were it appears that this type of validation is desired. I cannot figure out what is triggering this behavior.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Here is a screen shot of the message shown upon submit.

[image]

Razor Code snippet

```
<EditForm Model="@Values" OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <p class="text-center">@GasComps[0].ID</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <p class="text-center">@GasComps[0].Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <p class="text-center">@GasComps[0].AMW</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" @bind="GasComps[0].Quantity" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <p class="text-center">@GasComps[0].WtFraction</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Calculate</button>
        </div>
```

Model Code snippet

```
public double Quantity { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set step to [any](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp). This is default validation behaviour for `<input type=number ... />` .

`<input type="number" class="form-control text-center" @bind="GasComps[0].Quantity" step="any" />`

Comment: Thanks Brian Parker, I figured it was some default behavior but I couldn't find the right Google question to ask that would point me in the right direction.